# pass extra attribute in @html.textboxFor - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am trying to pass extra attribute 'data_id 'in @HTML.TextBoxFor... but I am getting no result

what I am missing in following code...

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model._MarkScheme.MarkSchemeId, new { id = "_MarkSchemeId_Input", @class = "ElementMarkingSchemeTitle k1-grid-input k-textbox_3", data_id =  @item.ElementID + "EMST"})
```

Many Thanks

Comment: By "no result" you mean there is no such attribute in the final HTML?

Comment: correct i can't see any data_id attribute in <input>...

Comment: Are you expecting to see `data_id` or `data-id`? Do you see other attributes?

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Answer (score 3):

Underscores aren't valid in HTML attribute names so Razor converts it to a hyphen. This will render with a `data-id` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

HTML 5 `data-*` attributes are expected to be `data_*` in ASP.Net MVC view engine to render it.

HTML syntax

```
<input type="text" data-my-id="5" value="something" />
```

MVC syntax

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new {data_my_id=@item.ID})
```

Your case it is `data-id`